# The camera does not open the application to take a photo and upload it

Tags: dart, flutter

When I click on the avatar and want to upload a photo, I need to choose to upload it from the gallery or take a photo. If you click to select from the gallery, everything works fine. But if you click to take a photo, the dialog box just closes and nothing happens.

> Help I can not get rid of this problem!

[My GitHub with project](https://github.com/belichenk0andreyka/GitHubFirstApp/blob/Json_branch/lib/account_screen/account_screen.dart)

```
    import 'dart:io';
import 'package:logining/account_screen/button_countries.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

String imagePath = 'images/user.png';

class AccountScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  _AccountScreenState createState() => _AccountScreenState();
}

class _AccountScreenState extends State<AccountScreen> {
  imageSelectorGallery() async {
    final File imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    setState(() {
      if (imageFile != null) imagePath = imageFile.path;
    });
  }

  imageSelectorCamera() async {
    final File imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );
    setState(() {
      if (imageFile != null) imagePath = imageFile.path;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AvatarScreen'),
        ),
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Form(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                IconButton(
                    iconSize: 150,
                    icon: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage(imagePath),
                      radius: 150,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                                title: Text('Choise a method to save a image'),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text('Make a photo'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      imageSelectorCamera();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text('Photo from gallery'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      imageSelectorGallery();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ));
                    }),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
```

File pubspeck.yaml

```
 dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  image_picker: 
  url_launcher: ^4.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide permissions on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```